# How can I verify I don't need the mLab add-on for my Heroku node.js app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

After reading through the mLab -> Atlas [migration plan](https://docs.mlab.com/how-to-migrate-sandbox-heroku-addons-to-atlas) a few times, I decided I'd try a different way.  My coding background is mainly asm on mcs51 so I'm something of a n00b in the node.js/mongo/heroku world. I barely understood half of the migration process.

So I wrote a small test app following [this blog entry](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database) and then used what I'd learned to modify my actual app to talk to Atlas directly.  I exported the collections from the old db to JSON, then imported them into the Atlas version to recreate the database.  Everything appears to be working correctly; I don't see any data going into the old db and it looks like the new Atlas db is getting all the action.

But I'm leery of deleting the mLab add-on from Heroku until I've verified that it's truly not needed any more, because I'm pretty sure that I won't be able to recreate it if it turns out I've missed something.

So my question is, how can I ensure I'm no longer using the mLab add-on?  I don't really understand what it was doing for me in the first place so I'm not sure how to verify I'm not using it any more.

Here are the relevant code snippets I'm using to access the Atlas db...

```
function myEncode(str) { // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}

const ATLASURI  = process.env.ATLASURI;
const ATLASDB   = process.env.ATLASDB;
const ATLASUSER = process.env.ATLASUSER;
const ATLASPW   = myEncode(process.env.ATLASPW); // wrapper needed to handle strong paswords...
const dbURL     = "mongodb+srv://"+ATLASUSER+":"+ATLASPW+"@"+ATLASURI+"/"+ATLASDB+"?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(dbURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

var store   = new MongoDBStore({uri: dbURL,collection: 'Sessions'});

var db = undefined;
client.connect(async function(err) {
  if(err) {console.log("Error:\n"+String(err));}
  db = await client.db(ATLASDB);
  console.log("Connected to db!");
  banner();
});
```

Comment: You can deploy your application into a new account on the heroku free tier.

Comment: You are sure you don't need mLab anymore if the migration was successful and the app works fine with the new Atlas DB. The connection string(`dbUrl` in your case) is what establishes a dependency between your app and the database(Atlas, mLab or any other), once you change that string value, your app is not more dependant on whatever the previous value(and associated service) was.

Comment: Tunmee if you repost that as an answer I'll accept it.  I deleted the add-on and the app sailed on smoothly.  Important note, though, in case it's not entirely clear:  Deleting the mLab add-on also deletes the associated database.  So backup first!  (Always good advice :- )